# Python and set() operations ... & and ^

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to do some JSON document comparisons by using python 2.7 sets.
I have scrubbed the py docs to understand set operations

In previous code, I make sure the JSON docs have exact Field matches

```
# convert the JSON to two set() for later operations
currSet = set(currJSON.items())
prevSet = set(prevJSON.items())

match   = currSet & prevSet 
unmatch = currSet ^ prevSet

log.info('%d, %d, Matched: %d, UnMatched: %d' % (len(currSet), len(prevSet), len(match), len(unmatch))
```

I always get len(currSet)==len(prevSet)
and expect len(currSet) == len(match)+len(unmatch)

```
match = S1 & S2  # this is the intersection, elements in both sets
umatch = S1 ^ S2  # this is the outersection, elements in (S1 not S2) and (S2 not S1)
```

Shouldn't: len(match) + len(umatch) == len(S1)

Something ain't clicking in my brain ....

Comment: Sorry ... this was overthinking on my side ....

the length of the UnMatch set includes elements from both sides, S1 and S2

so: len(match) + (len(umatch)/2) == len(S1)

doh ....

Comment: already pointed out in my answer

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing the `sum` of the `union` and `symmetric difference` to the length of just `one set`

```
In [80]: S1 = set([1,1,2,3])

In [81]: S2 = set([1,2,2,4])

In [82]: match = S1 & S2

In [83]: unmatch = S1 ^ S2

In [84]: match
Out[84]: {1, 2}

In [85]: unmatch
Out[85]: {3, 4}

In [86]: length = len(match)+len(unmatch)

In [87]: length
Out[87]: 4

In [88]: len(S2)  # len of just S2 not len of union and intersection
Out[88]: 3
```